# Check if Sailjs backend is getting a legit req from the frontend without any authentication system

Tags: sails.js, restful-authentication

I do not want my users to authenticate. But I do not anyone to steal my data. So my goal is to only serve the people who make a req from the front end of the app. How can I do this ?

Is there a built in function that I'm missing ? I know that there are session id generated, but not sure how to incorporate the session id to this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the term "front end" I would assume that you have a client requesting data in the form of JSON/XML or HTML templates. My first suggestion to get your answer is to be much more descriptive in your question. It is very hard to answer without knowing how your client is designed.

Assuming your client is written in html/js and run in a browser then I would suggest that you serve a static file (in the form of a .js file or a <script></script> tag inside an html file) that generates a token. You can pass this token back to your server for validation on every request for data. This means that only your app (front-end) can be the only thing that requests data from your api (back-end).

Comment: What you assumed was correct. Thanks for the tip. Although generating a random token and sending it to the client is no problem. But with what do I compare it to on the backend ? Do you get my point ?

Comment: You could encrypt a timestamp as your token, thus giving each token a lifespan. Then when you check it, you can validate that it is a timestamp and that it is not expired. Or you could encrypt the machines IP address and browser info and compare it each time to make sure they token was not re-purposed. It all depends on the level of security I suppose.

Comment: Yep. Need to have the performance in mind too. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Performance is not much of an issue really. It has been shown that decryption token based authentication can be just as fast as a session store based authentication. Unless your session store livesin memory on the same server as the application accessing it, it will pretty much be the same.